# Determine if the following is surjective

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I need to determine if $f: \Bbb N\times\Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ such that $f(a,b) = a^b$ is a surjective (onto) function. My intuition is that it is but I don't know how to prove it. I don't even know how to represent this graphically. Help appreciated

Answer (score 16):

Hint: what is $f(a,1)$? $\,\,\,\,$

Comment: This is where a hint is most appropriate as an answer IMO. +1

Answer (score 3):

**Proof:** Let $\eta$ be an arbitrary element in $\mathbb{N}$. Then
$$
f(\eta,1) = \eta^1 = \eta\in\mathbb{N}. \blacksquare
$$

---

This answer gives you the proof that the mapping $f\colon\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ defined by $f(a,b)=a^b$ is onto, and it makes use of Cameron's hint. Can you see why the above constitutes a proof?

Comment: Is the proof that every single element in the range can be expressed as itself raised to the power of 1? So everything has to be hit right?

Comment: @Sammy You have the basic idea right, but you may want to clean up your phrasing to be precise--every element in the *codomain* (i.e., some element $\eta\in\mathbb{N}$) is mapped to by *at least* one element in the domain, where here the elements in the domain are ordered pairs and your "at least" element may be thought of as $(\eta, 1)$. My reason for answering was to show you how you would write your proof. Does it make sense now? Sense $\eta$ was arbitrary, you can say that *all* elements in $\mathbb{N}$ are mapped to; hence, $f$ is surjective.

Comment: Just wondering, how come you used a greek eta symbol rather than a plain n? Not criticising, just curious if it has any special significance...

Comment: @Thomas No special significance. The symbol $\eta$ is really just a placeholder--any other symbol would work. It could have been: "Let $\stackrel{..}{\smile}$ be an arbitrary element in $\mathbb{N}$; then $f(\stackrel{..}{\smile}, 1)={\stackrel{..}{\smile}} ^1=\stackrel{..}{\smile}\in\mathbb{N}$," but that looks rather silly doesn't it? Haha.